# Is scraped content supported by Google Adsense

Tags: google, google-adsense, google-adsense-policies, scraper-sites

Scraper site is an abbreviation of "screen scraper site"

screen scraping is a technique where automated tools are used to download a web page and extract (scrape) some of the information on that page in order to place it on another web page.

For Example: http://www.siteworthtraffic.com/

This site extracts data from Alexa and then estimates the daily revenue of a website. I found Google ads on the site.
http://www.siteworthtraffic.com/report/stackoverflow.com

Does Google support like this content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you gave is not really a "scraper site".   Scraper sites as I understand them, scrape full content and re-host it illegally.   See [this definition from What Is](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/scraper-site):

> A scraper site is a website that features content stolen from other sites and presented as original.

Scraped content infringes on the copyright of the owners of that content.   Google AdSense doesn't support content that does that per [their policy](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1348688):

> Google ads may not be placed on any page that contains content that is illegal, promotes illegal activity, or infringes on the legal rights of others.

[Google says](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9892?hl=en) that if you find scraped content, you should report it to them and they will terminate the account of the infringer:

> It is our policy to respond to notices of alleged infringement that comply with the Digital Millennium Copyright Act (DMCA). For AdSense publishers, if we receive a notice or otherwise have reason to believe that your page is infringing, we may terminate your participation in the program. You can file a counter-notification via [this form](https://support.google.com/legal/contact/lr_counternotice?product=websearch). More information about our DMCA process is available in this [blog post](http://adsense.blogspot.com/2012/08/policy-tips-avoiding-copyright.html).
>
> If you believe that a site which is participating in the AdSense program is displaying your copyrighted material without the rights to do so, please report it using this [form](https://support.google.com/adsense/contact/violation_report) or by clicking on the AdChoices icon.

The example you gave would not be a scraper site.   It would be a "information about other sites" type of site.  It might reproduce a small amount of information about the site, such as a screen shot of the home page.   Such limited amount of copying seems to me to be transformative under copyright law.  It is used in the context of commentary and review.  Such use would likely be allowed under the "fair use" exception to copyright.   As such, your example site it not likely to be breaking the law and would be allowed to use Google Adsense.